# Trying to SUM with multi-vector conditions

Tags: excel, sumifs

Thanks in advance.

I'm trying to Sum the Capital impact of CRs from the list in rows 15-24 (ignoring Invoices).  I have tried using SUMIFs, SUMPRODUCT, and nested IFs, but so far nothing has worked.

I am putting the formula in D4.

The CR indicator is in Column L.

The Capital indicator can be seen in Columns N, Q, T, and W

I SHOULD be seeing a result of $350 if the formula is working correctly.

What ridiculously easy thing am I missing?

[image: See a screenshot of the file I'm working with here]

Comment: Sum the row where `L` = `CR` and the Title in Row `14` is `CAP`?  Will `CR` only happen once in column `L`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SuMPRODUCT(($L$15:$L$24="CR")*($M$14:$X$14="CAP")*$M$15:$X$24)
```

[image]

Comment: @MichaelTaylor please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.